# Export csv in fixed number of lines from php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am using this code to generate csv files from a mysql db.

I don t how how to do for export csv's with maxim 500 rows.
For example if i found 1100 results on query i want to have as result 3 csv files, 1 two with 500 lines and third one with 100 lines.

```
    <?php
include "connection.php";
$filename = 'export.csv';

$fp = fopen($filename, "w");

$res = mysql_query("SELECT id, name, first_name, middle_name, last_name, phone FROM data WHERE active='1' ");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$line = "";
$comma = "";
foreach($row as $name => $value) {
    $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $name) . '"';
    $comma = ",";
}
$line .= "\n";
fputs($fp, $line);

mysql_data_seek($res, 0);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {

    $line = "";
    $comma = "";
    foreach($row as $value) {
        $line .= $comma . '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $value) . '"';
        $comma = ",";
    }
    $line .= "\n";
    fputs($fp, $line);

}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: Won't answer the question but will help with generating .csv files: http://php.net/fputcsv

Answer (score 0):

Count the number of line you are putting into the file. If count is divisible by 500 without remainder (count % 500 == 0) then close the file you were writing in and open new file.